# OHAttributedLabel + case value not in enumerated type "UItextAlignment"

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I am using OHAttributedLabel in my application and getting an warning please tell me how to resolve it.

```
case value not in enumerated type "UItextAlignment"
```

Anyone please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already fixed since multiple commits.
Just update your `OHAttributedLabel` version to the latest version.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the latest version but now I am getting a warning UITextalignment is depreciated : You should use setTextAlignment:lineBreakMode:on your NSAttributedString instead can you please help me in this.

Comment: Errr.... why don't you just do what the warning says? Use `setTextAlignment:lineBreakMode:` on your attributed string instead of setting UITextAlignementJustified on your attributedLabel (because iOS6 will now throw an exception if you try to use this OOB value).

You could at least have read the examples provided with my project that show exactly how to do this, and read the related (now closed) issue on GitHub that explains in details why it is now deprecated and why you should use the new way to justify your text instead.

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you. However, now everything has disappeared. Im wondering if I keep on using the old version with warnings will apple reject my app? Please suggest.

Comment: If you use the special (unofficial) `UITextAlignmentJustified` value (that is if you set the `textAlignemnt` property of your `UILabel`/`OHAttributedLabel` to something that evaluates to the value `3`), your app will crash under the upcoming iOS 6.0 (as the iOS6 runtime now throws an exception for this case).

Comment: See issues #79 and #80 on github. Until then, apply the patch explained in #80.

Comment: I tried now it showing the label but the text with black color but I wanted the  label text different color i.e white, red and green color.Also I tried to change the color in the sample code given by you but it didn't happen [attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:[txt rangeOfString:@TXT_BOLD]];

Comment: Thanks you I got the solution from the issue you have suggested.

Comment: FYI, I just did a commit to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/downloads) link and its better than OHAttributedLabel to use all functionality of NSAttributedString